# How to procedurally evaluate a sequence that maximizes color contrast, limited to HSV(-, 100%, 100%)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following continuous functions:

- $\text{conv} : \text{Hue} \to \text{Lab}$, which converts a hue into a CIEL*a*b* point
- $\text{cont} : \left(\text{Lab} \times \text{Lab}\right) \to \mathbb{R}^+$, which measures the contrast between two CIEL*a*b* colors

$\text{Hue} = [0, 360)$ and $\text{Lab} = \mathbb{R}^3$.

Given some $a_1 : \text{Hue}$, I want to find any $a_n$ that maximizes contrast against the previous values in the sequence, weighted against recent values. For example perhaps something like the following may be a solution:

$$
\begin{align}
a_2 &= \text{max}_{x}\left(\frac{1}{1}\text{cont}\left(\text{conv}\left(a_1\right), \text{conv}\left(x\right)\right)\right) \\
a_3 &= \text{max}_{x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\text{cont}\left(\text{conv}\left(a_1\right), \text{conv}\left(x\right)\right) + \frac{1}{1}\text{cont}\left(\text{conv}\left(a_2\right), \text{conv}\left(x\right)\right)\right) \\
a_4 &= \text{max}_{x}\left(\frac{1}{3}\text{cont}\left(\text{conv}\left(a_1\right), \text{conv}\left(x\right)\right) + \frac{1}{2}\text{cont}\left(\text{conv}\left(a_2\right), \text{conv}\left(x\right)\right) + \frac{1}{1}\text{cont}\left(\text{conv}\left(a_3\right), \text{conv}\left(x\right)\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$

I'd prefer a solution simpler than brute-forcing; as far as I know, $\text{max}$ has to be brute-forced. A quick Google implied that "Loop Algebra" are related to my problem, as $\text{Hue}$ is a loop, but I'm not familiar with Lie algebra at all.

Some additional information:

- Applying $\text{conv}$ to the entire $\text{Hue}$ circle does not create an ellipsoid in the output space.
- $\text{conv}$ is injective.
- $\text{cont}$ is commutative.
- $\text{cont}$ is neither injective nor surjective.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to write out $\operatorname{conv}$ and $\operatorname{cont}$ explicitly?

Comment: @cwindolf $\operatorname{cont}$ is just the distance between the two input vectors (the magnitude of the differences). $\operatorname{conv}$ is incredibly long, but the process is HSV -> sRGB -> Linear RGB (D65 Illuminant, Standard Space) -> CIE XYZ (D65 Illuminant) -> CIELab. When I implemented these transformations in https://gitlab.com/srnb/nose , I got most of the equations/procedures from Wikipedia, but for Linear RGB to CIE XYZ I had to use http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html . Would it suffice to write out $\operatorname{conv}$ in Mathematica?

Comment: It doesn't look too great. https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/86fceb5c-e78a-4c1e-9988-d316a772c6b0